# How to write serverless.yml with API gateway only (no resources)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to create an API gateway with a GET endpoint using **serverless.yml** without any resource. All I want it to do is to return 200 if successful. All the resources I have looked at online connect to some sort of AWS resource but there is no example of how to write out the serverless.yml with it.

Comment: Would this from the documentation help?  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-test-method.html

Comment: That just tells me how to do it via the aws console but I want to translate this to serverless.yml code where I can just deploy it via the CLI

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a mock, right? If so just follow the steps:

Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/main/precreate
[image]

Fill these informations:
[image]

Now you need to create a method, in your case, a **GET.**
[image]

Select mock on the next page:
[image]

Select Actions again and Deploy API:
[image]

Fill these infos:
[image]

After that you will see a URL like:

Invoke URL: https://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxx -- Which is your API endpoint returning a blank page with 200 response code.

Comment: Um yeah this is using the AWS console but I want to know how to translate this to serverless.yml so that when I deploy it it will create the API gateway in the console. If that makes sense?

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't get it. By serverles.yml you mean https://www.serverless.com/?

Comment: Yeah here is an example template https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml

I think I might have an idea now actually. Will post the answer to this question once I have resolved it.